# Как правильно составить и ответить на длинные опрос?

Tags: php, javascript, comet

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь сделать длинный опрос. То есть я хочу сделать так, что бы клиент не посылал очередной запрос до того, как не прешел ответ с сервера. В моем случае ответы должны приходить раз в минуту. Вот так выглядит код php:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$minutes = $date->format("i");
if($minutes%2 == 0){
  print "Сервер отправил запрос";
}
?>
```

Вот js:

```
  function subscribe(url) {
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState != 4) return;

    if (this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    } else {
       console.log(this);
    }

    subscribe(url);
  }
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.send();
}
subscribe("http://comet/php.php")
```

В итоге несколько раз в секунду в консоль выстреливается несколько десяток сообщений, аналогичных этому:

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://comet/php.php"
```

Судя по всему у меня сервер все время шлет ответы. Но как мне сделать так, что бы сервер отправлял ответы только если количество текущих минут делится на 2 без остатка? Как сделать все правильно? Или проблема в js? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ваш php-код отрабатывает и отправляет ответ. Если минуты делятся на 2, то ещё и дописывает в тело ответа 'Сервер отправил запрос'. Вам надо разобраться с тем что такое HTTP-запрос и как и когда он отправляется в php. Очень грубо говоря, у вас должен быть цикл с выходом по $minutes%2. Но обратите внимание, что такой php-процесс подвиснет на всё время цикла, и в зависимости от настроек сервера либо отвалится по таймауту либо их накопится много и сервер не сможет создать новый. Поэтому вам нужен отдельный long polling сервер -- демон, который будет держать много открытых соединений.

Comment: Возможно, вам надо рассказать в вашем вопросе, чего вы хотите добиться этим? Зачем вам длинный запрос?

Comment: Stepan Kasyanenko, чисто ради практики. Мне нужно просто получать ответы тогда, когда проверка в if даст true. И выводить ответ сервера в консоль.
Я хочу что бы было примерно так: <?php
sleep(3);
$date = new DateTime();
$minutes = $date->format("i");
if($minutes%2 == 0){
 print "Сервер отправил запрос";
}
?>